# Exception with SessionHandler in magento242

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

The problem appeared on the site dump, on the front page

> Exception: Warning: SessionHandler::read():
> open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73/sess_otpvdk0an5tso42ofv0df1f359,
> O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in
> /var/www/vhosts/7.4/crazy/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php
> on line 22 in
> /var/www/vhosts/7.4/crazy/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
> Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
> Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler() #1
> /var/www/vhosts/7.4/crazy/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php(22): SessionHandler->read()

Comment: i just delete file pub/.user.ini and it works

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could do:

Confirm that your `session.save_path` in `php.ini` matches the directory that Magento is saving sessions.

In app/etc/env.php make sure session looks like:

```
   'session' => [
        'save' => 'files'
    ],
```

Make sure the session save path has proper permissions.

If you have the resources, I would recommend using redis to save sessions.